# Direct3D11 crash and/or glitches on resizing window

Tags: direct3d11

I am currently porting a rendering engine from OpenGL to Direct3D11

Its working fine on my development machine, but having now released it to a few beta testers, 2 testers are reporting a problem on resizing the window (one a crash, the other UI freezing).  As it works on my machine, and I cant see anything wrong in the code, I hope someone with more Direct3D experience might be able to spot what I'm doing wrong.

Code below is the relevant code what happens when the window resizes (the m_stencilview etc are smart pointers to Com objects, D3D_CHECK is a macro wrapper for checking the result)

```
m_stencilview.Clear();

m_stencil.Clear();

m_rendertargetview.Clear();


ctx.OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0);
    
D3D_CHECK(m_swpchain->ResizeBuffers(0, 0, 0, DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, 0));
   

ComPtr <ID3D11Texture2D> framebuffer;

D3D_CHECK(m_swpchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&framebuffer));

D3D_CHECK(engine.m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(framebuffer, 0, &m_rendertargetview));
```

Comment: Double check if you actually managed to release the render target views as intended, or if the com pointer has also gotten additional owners in the meantime! A not yet submitted deferred context can also cause trouble, same as still queued commands. So make sure to `Flush` before tearing down the old swap chain.

Comment: Im pretty sure there are no additional owners (within my code).  So I will try a flush.  Should I also be recreating the swap chain when the window resizes?

Comment: Even if you are (more or less) sure, [ComPtr::Reset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/comptr-class?view=msvc-160#reset) will tell you for certain if the reference count has *actually* dropped to 0 and the resource has been released.

Answer (score 3):

Note that a key problem is this:

```
ctx.OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0);
```

This doesn't clear the set render target at all. You need to actually pass an array of nullptr to get it to clear the binding:

```
ID3D11RenderTargetView* nullViews [] = { nullptr };
ctx.OMSetRenderTargets(1, nullViews, nullptr);
```

> If you were using "Multiple render targets" then you'd have to pass more than one nullptr which is why an array is simple and easy to use here.

Additionally, you need to check the `HRESULT` coming from `ResizeBuffers` at runtime. Currently you just treat it as if it will always succeed, which is not true.

In particular, you need to check both `ResizeBuffers` and `Present` for the return values `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED` or `DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET`.

The most common reason for this at runtime is when the device driver is updated in the background while the application is running. It can also happen if the driver crashes and restarts or if the GPU hardware hangs and timeouts.

You have two basic choices:

(a) fatally error with a message-box like "You have to restart this application now.". That's lame, but at least it's clear what happened.

(b) A better response is to basically do what Direct3D 9 apps did for "lost device": Destroy all Direct3D objects and recreate them.

> You can test this behavior with a recent Visual Studio release by running `dxcap -forcetdr` from the Developer Command Prompt (opened as admin) while your Direct3D application is running.

See [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp) for complete game loops with handling for 'lost device'.

See also [Timeout detection and recovery (TDR)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/timeout-detection-and-recovery)

Comment: Thanks, i will have to check the response.  but is it not possible to safely resize the buffers at run time, without needing to destroy all D3D objects?

Comment: You can resize buffers at runtime, but it's one of the two points of failure (along with ``Present``) for this "device removed" thing so you can't just assume the function always return ``S_OK``. That said, I updated the answer to what I think is another problem in your code.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn regarding your comment on the proper use of OMSetRenderTargets - the official docs also suggest to do just `OMSetRenderTargets(0, 0, 0)` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#handling-window-resizing
Are the official docs wrong?